# Qt или WinAPI для десктоп приложения

Tags: winapi, qt, c++

Здравствуйте.

Решил взять себе какой-нибудь проект для получения опыта. Все, что смог придумать, это что-то вроде центра уведомлений, как в хроме. 
Встал вопрос: использовать Qt WinAPI.

WinAPI привлекает взаимодействием с системой напрямую, но как-то страшно за него браться. А Qt напрягает весом библиотек. Тем более, если уведомления будут браться из расширений в виде dll и если каждое будет написано на Qt, то получается возня с библиотеками, если на какой-нибудь машине отсутствует Qt.

Может посоветуете что-нибудь?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Учитывая, что Вы похоже плохо знаете и то, и другое, то я бы рекомендовал попробовать оба. сделав какое-то минимальное приложение, реализующее Вашу идею. Очень скоро Вы поймете, что Qt хоть и тянет за собой много, но реализовать проще. А WinAPI, хотя и требовать будет меньше, но время заберет значительно больше.

Мое мнение - напишите это вначале на Qt (или даже на другом - С#, Delphi. FASM+WinAPI), главное, что бы получить работающий прототип. А потом перепишите его на других языках (в Вашем случае обязательно на Qt и WinAPI). И после этого Вы сами сможете ответить на свой вопрос.

Answer (score -5):

Попробуйте на C# на фрэймвёрке .net 
Qt это больше для линуксов

Comment: о да, Qt это для линуксов:).

Comment: вредные советы от Григория Остера?